# How can I add dynamic part to HTML file each X time?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, .net, winforms

I am using Netbeans to edit my HTML file. This is the first part of my HTML code file (I have some  more code inside the head tags however that is not important):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>


  </head>
      <body>  

         <!-- wrapper for the whole component -->
         <div id="componentWrapper">

              <!-- playlist -->
              <div class="componentPlaylist">

                 <div class="menuHolder">
                     <div class="menuWrapper">
                     </div>
                 </div>

                 <div class="thumbHolder">
                     <div class="thumbWrapper">
```

The dynamic part is in my C# program that create automatic on the hard disk an event each X time and put for me in a directory some gif files along with one animated gif (the animated gif shows animation of the other gif files in the directory). In this part of the HTML after the line: `<div class="thumbWrapper">` 
I need to add the dynamic part in this format for example:

```
<div class="playlist" data-address='mistique_ken_burns' data-title='mistique' data-transitionType='ken_burns' data-bgColor='#e5e5e5' data-playlistSize='165' data-duration="25000">
                                   <ul> 
<li data-address='image1' class='playlistItem' data-imagePath='media/category1/main/01.jpg' data-startScale="1.4" data-endScale="0.5" data-startPosition="tl" data-endPosition="br" data-link='http://www.google.com' data-target='_blank' data-description="hello quam.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='http://codecanyon.net/user/Tean' target='_blank'>Link</a>" data-youtube='F08U2yCxbYg'><a href='#'><img src='media/category1/thumb/01.jpg' width='120' height='80' alt=''/></a></li>
                                  </ul> 
                             </div>
```

There are more `<li> </li>` lines. The important thing here is inside the li tags:

```
data-address='image1' class='playlistItem' data-imagePath='media/category1/main/01.jpg'
```

image1 then the next one is image2 then image3 and so on...
Then `playlistItem` the next time I will add to the HTML a block like this inside div tags it will be playlistItem2 then playlistItem3....

And the links to the images now it's: `media/category1/main/01.jpg`
But next time next block it will be `media/category2/main/01.jpg`

Then in the end I have another some HTML code that I don't change and then in my C# program, I merge the three parts every time and upload the updated HTML file to my FTP.

The first part is static, then dynamic part, and in the end another static part.

My question is how do I build each time adding to the dynamic part?

For example on my hard disk I have new event inside one .jpg file.
The file uploaded to my FTP server.

So now the HTML code I need to add in the HTML file, for example:

```
<div class="playlist" data-address='mistique_ken_burns' data-title='mistique' data-transitionType='ken_burns' data-bgColor='#e5e5e5' data-playlistSize='165' data-duration="25000">
                                       <ul> 
    <li data-address='image1' class='playlistItem2' data-imagePath='media/category2/main/01.jpg' data-startScale="1.4" data-endScale="0.5" data-startPosition="tl" data-endPosition="br" data-link='http://www.google.com' data-target='_blank' data-description="hello quam.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='http://codecanyon.net/user/Tean' target='_blank'>Link</a>" data-youtube='F08U2yCxbYg'><a href='#'><img src='media/category2/thumb/01.jpg' width='120' height='80' alt=''/></a></li>
                                      </ul> 
                                 </div>
```

My question is how in C# I can dynamically update the HTML file in this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use placeholders inside the html file. Those placeholders can be replaced at runtime as below:

```
        string placeHolder = "<!--<<PLACEHOLDER>>-->";
        string path = "C:\\test.html";

        string dynamicContent = @"<div class='playlist' data-address='mistique_ken_burns' data-title='mistique' data-transitionType='ken_burns' data-bgColor='#e5e5e5' data-playlistSize='165' data-duration='25000'>
                               <ul> 
                                    <li data-address='image1' class='playlistItem' data-imagePath='media/category1/main/01.jpg' data-startScale='1.4' data-endScale='0.5' data-startPosition='tl' data-endPosition='br' 
                                        data-link='http://www.google.com' data-target='_blank' data-description='hello quam.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='http://codecanyon.net/user/Tean' target='_blank'>Link</a>' 
                                        data-youtube='F08U2yCxbYg'><a href='#'><img src='media/category1/thumb/01.jpg' width='120' height='80' alt=''/></a></li>
                              </ul> 
                         </div>";
        string content = File.ReadAllText(path).Replace(placeHolder, string.Concat(dynamicContent, placeHolder));
        File.WriteAllText(path, content);
```